# Yii authentication fails on server works on localhost

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii framework and created `UserIdentity` component to authenticate users which works correctly but when I put my code on Server it gives me error saying:

> Array ( [user_id] => Array ( [0] => User cannot be blank. )
>   [logout_time] => Array ( [0] => Logout Time cannot be blank. ) )

Any comments which will help me to reach the root of the problem would be beneficial.

Comment: recheck your database and the values stored; or maybe you forgot to upload something; also, pls give us the code that logs the user;

Answer (score 0):

Your model's rules have user_id and logout_time marked as required for some reason. you should only declare rules to validate **user submitted** data. check [the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#declaring-validation-rules) for more information.